# Can not get Client Ip by Socket Server

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

I have a socket server to catch HTTP request from Client. I want to get Client's Ip so I used these code :

```
var sIp = (socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':'))[0];
IPAddress rIp = IPAddress.Parse(sIp);
string clientIp = rIp.ToString();
```

But the Ip returned was wrong and there was an Exception : ' 'rIp' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'

Do anyone have solution for this case ? Tks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has this information on socket.RemoteEndpoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.remoteendpoint.aspx

The key part is "You must cast this EndPoint to an IPEndPoint before retrieving any information."

So the code could be re-written as:

```
IPEndPoint remoteIP = (IPEndpoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint();
IPAddress rIp = (IpAddress)remoteIP.Address;
string clientIP = rIp.ToString()
```

however the rIp isn't needed you could just do:

```
IPEndPoint remoteIP = (IPEndpoint)socket.RemoteEndPoint();
string clientIP = remoteIP.Address.ToString();
```